# How to figure out if your cursor is pointing at your desktop under X11

Tags: c++, c, linux, debian, x11

How can I check whether my mouse cursor is not pointing at a window? I'm programming with C/C++ and for X11 (especially the gnome3 shell)

Comment: That's an interesting question. Figuring out if it's entered or left your window is pretty easy. But figuring out if it's currently pointed there isn't trivial. I expect that GTK or the GNOME toolkit provides a way though, which is might where you want to be hunting, not the raw X11 API.

Answer (score 3):

If the desktop is really the X11 root window then I think `XQueryPointer` does what you want: just test whether `child_return == root_return`. Make sure you call `XQueryPointer` with `RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display))` or `XDefaultRootWindow(display)`.

Comment: OK. Maybe it is trivial. This is complicated by the fact that I suspect that GNOME doesn't use sub-windows for the controls like Xt and Motif did. If that's true, you can't find what sub-control you're pointing at with `XQueryPointer`.

Answer (score 2):

Certain desktop environments may utilize a separate window (X11 definition) that **is not the root window**. xwininfo onto the desktop that one can slap icons on gives, in xfce4, for example:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1c00003 "Skrivebord"

  Absolute upper-left X:  0
  Absolute upper-left Y:  0
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1024
  Height: 600
  [...]
```

So, though you could determine what your mouse is pointing at, there is no way to tell whether it is what is commonly referred to "desktop" (since that term itself is not precisely defined in the context of X11.)